# How to solve the following infinite ladder fraction? ( Through pen & paper )

Tags: sequences-and-series, continued-fractions, infinite-sequences

[The fraction continues till infinity as shown in the image :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1eIH.jpg)

Comment: MO is not the appropriate setting for this question.  You could ask on our sister site MSE, but they will want to know what you have tried.

Comment: They will also not be happy with a link to an image, when the question should be written out in full on their site. Before you post there, please read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Answer (score 2):

You can find this continued fraction at Sloane's https://oeis.org/A111129

Answer (score 2):

The limit is $$\dfrac{\sqrt{2/\pi e}}{erfc(1/\sqrt{2})}\;,$$
where $e=2.718...$ and $erfc$ is the complementary error function.